Type mismatch creating an angular FormGroup using a custom FormGroup
I want to be able to define my own methods for a custom angular FormGroup. So I created a class that extends the default angular formgroup, and I want it to be of the same type as IUnitForm
initForm(): FormGroup<IForm> {
    return this.formBuilder.group<IForm>({
        weight: new UnitFormGroup<MassUnit>({
            unit: new FormControl<MassUnit>(MassUnit.gram),
            unitValue: new FormControl<number>(11)
        } as IUnitForm<MassUnit>)
    });
}

export interface IForm {
    weight: UnitFormGroup<UnitType>;
}

export class UnitFormGroup<T extends UnitType> extends FormGroup implements IUnitForm<T> {
    unit: FormControl<T>;
    unitValue: FormControl<number>;

    constructor(controls: IUnitForm<T>) {
        super(controls);
        this.unit = controls.unit;
        this.unitValue = controls.unitValue;
    }

    addOne(): void {
        const newValue = this.unitValue.value + 1;
        console.log(newValue);
    }
}

export type UnitType = MassUnit | LengthUnit | DistanceUnit | SpeedUnit | TemperatureUnit;

export enum MassUnit {
    gram = 'gram',
    grain = 'grain',
    ounce = 'ounce'
}

export enum LengthUnit {
    millimeter = 'millimeter',
    inch = 'inch'
}

export enum DistanceUnit {
    meter = 'meter',
    yard = 'yard'
}

export enum SpeedUnit {
    meterSecond = 'meterSecond',
    feetSecond = 'feetSecond'
}

export enum TemperatureUnit {
    celsius = 'celsius',
    fahrenheit = 'fahrenheit'
}

export interface IUnitForm<T extends UnitType> {
    unit: FormControl<T>;
    unitValue: FormControl<number>;
}

On return this.formBuilder.group<IForm> I get the error
Type 'FormGroup<{ weight: FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }>; }>' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<IForm>'.
  Types of property 'controls' are incompatible.
    Type '{ weight: FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }>; }' is not assignable to type 'IForm'.ts(2322)

How can I fix this type mismatch?

Remove the return type: FormGroup<IForm> from the initForm method, it should work. as with FormBuilder.group<T>() returns a instance of FormGroup<{ [K in keyof T]: ɵElement<T[K], null>; }> type

@YongShun Is there no way to explicitly type this?

Ya, I don't think so. Otherwise you should create a FormGroup<IForm> instance with new FormGroup<IForm>(...) instead of working with this.formBuilder.group<IForm>(...)

I think the typing of this.formBuild.group is the main cause of the problems, you can solve this by using new FormGroup instead.
Also in few places, it was complaing that the types should also be null, so I adjusted the types to also accept null values.
import { Component, HostListener, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';

export interface IForm {
  weight: UnitFormGroup<UnitType>;
}

export class UnitFormGroup<T extends UnitType>
  extends FormGroup
  implements IUnitForm<T>
{
  unit: FormControl<T | null>;
  unitValue: FormControl<number | null>;

  constructor(controls: IUnitForm<T>) {
    super(controls);
    this.unit = controls.unit;
    this.unitValue = controls.unitValue;
  }

  addOne(): void {
    const newValue = (this.unitValue!.value || 0) + 1;
    console.log(newValue);
  }
}

export type UnitType =
  | MassUnit
  | LengthUnit
  | DistanceUnit
  | SpeedUnit
  | TemperatureUnit;

export enum MassUnit {
  gram = 'gram',
  grain = 'grain',
  ounce = 'ounce',
}

export enum LengthUnit {
  millimeter = 'millimeter',
  inch = 'inch',
}

export enum DistanceUnit {
  meter = 'meter',
  yard = 'yard',
}

export enum SpeedUnit {
  meterSecond = 'meterSecond',
  feetSecond = 'feetSecond',
}

export enum TemperatureUnit {
  celsius = 'celsius',
  fahrenheit = 'fahrenheit',
}

export interface IUnitForm<T extends UnitType> {
  unit: FormControl<T | null>;
  unitValue: FormControl<number | null>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);
  loaded: any = false;

  initForm(): FormGroup<IForm> {
    return new FormGroup<IForm>({
      weight: new UnitFormGroup<MassUnit>({
        unit: new FormControl<MassUnit>(MassUnit.gram),
        unitValue: new FormControl<number>(11),
      }),
    }) as FormGroup<IForm>;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
